# Honeycomb css design with background-attachment: fixed and css transform issue - image not spanning across hexagons

Tags: css, css-transforms, background-attachment

I have a honeycomb css design and i am struggling to get the background image to span across all hexagons. At the moment the image repeats in each hexagon. I think there is a conflict between the css transforms and the fixed background.

Here is my codepen link : https://codepen.io/andymikellides/pen/OJzgWON

Here is my code:

```
<ul id="hexGrid" class="pb-5">
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <h4>test</h4>
      <p>inner content</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <h4>test</h4>
      <p>inner content</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <h4>test</h4>
      <p>inner content</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <h4>test</h4>
      <p>inner content</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <h4>test</h4>
      <p>inner content</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <h4>test</h4>
      <p>inner content</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <h4>test</h4>
      <p>inner content</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <h4>test</h4>
      <p>inner content</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <h4>test</h4>
      <p>inner content</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
    


#hexGrid {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0.707% 0;
}

#hexGrid:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.hex {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.hex * {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
}

.hexIn {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    
    background: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/539/200/300.jpg?hmac=anJssHN1m53jBatiVAldD8gSdk_3w_5WHOCNCFvGFkk") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

/* HEX CONTENT */

.hex h4 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
}

 .hex p {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(137, 179, 137);
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: top .4s ease-out, bottom .4s ease-out, .4s padding .4s ease-out;
            transition: top .4s ease-out, bottom .4s ease-out, .4s padding .4s ease-out;
}


.hex p {
    padding-top: 50%;
    top: 110%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}

/* HOVER EFFECT  */

.hexIn:hover p {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}


@media (min-width:1201px) {
    .hex {
        width: 19.2%; /* = (100-4) / 5 */
        padding-bottom: 22.170%; /* =  width / sin(60deg) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+6),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+7),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+8),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+9) {
        margin-top: -4.676%;
        margin-bottom: -4.676%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+6):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(9n+7):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(9n+8):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(9n+9):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+6) {
        margin-left: 0.5%;
        clear: left;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+10) {
        clear: left;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+2),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+ 7) {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+3),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+4),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+8) {
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:901px) {
    .hex {
        width: 24.25%; /* = (100-3) / 4 */
        padding-bottom: 28.001%; /* =  width / sin(60deg) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+5),
    .hex:nth-child(7n+6),
    .hex:nth-child(7n+7) {
        margin-top: -6.134%;
        margin-bottom: -6.134%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+5):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(7n+6):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(7n+7):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+2),
    .hex:nth-child(7n+6) {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+3) {
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+8) {
        clear: left;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+5) {
        clear: left;
        margin-left: 0.5%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:601px) {
    .hex {
        width: 32.666%; /* = (100-2) / 3 */
        padding-bottom: 37.720%; /* =  width / sin(60) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+4),
    .hex:nth-child(5n+5) {
        margin-top: -8.564%;
        margin-bottom: -8.564%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+4):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(5n+5):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+4) {
        margin-right: 1%;
        margin-left: 0.5%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+2) {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+6) {
        clear: left;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .hex {
        width: 49.5%; /* = (100-1) / 2 */
        padding-bottom: 57.158%; /* =  width / sin(60) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-top: -13.423%;
        margin-bottom: -13.423%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+3):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-left: 0.5%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+2) {
        margin-left: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+4) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

i would appreciate any kind of help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear top margin in `hover` state in `.hexIn:hover p` class

```
.hexIn:hover p {
 margin-top:0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/abdulmalik/pen/XWVgRRN

Comment: Hi Abdul , i want to make the background image to continue(span) on the other hexagons rather to repeat on each. I dont think the <p> hover has anything to do with this. I tried you suggestion with no luck. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: @AndyMikellides sorry i misunderstood your problem.